# C# ITypeResolutionService for constructed types

Tags: c#, types

My ITypeResolutionService is failing to return correct type for constructed type in an assembly:

```
e.g. "abc`N[aaa,bbb`1[string],....,mmm]"
```

how to get type information for this type.

I can get type for `abc'N` from the referenced assembly. 
Then i have to call makegenericType(Type[]) on this type in order to get constructed type. 
Is there any efficient way to parse the type arguments within the sqaure brackets in C#.
and as shown above type arguments can itself be constructed type e.g. bbb`1[string].

Wonder if .net provides any standard API for this.

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

[`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) supports this. For example, if I run the following:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
```

I get a constructed type representing a list of strings.

Comment: what if type is in some third party assembly. Type.GetType() reutnrs null for types not present in default(mscorlib.e.g.) .net assemblies.